# Android 8.1 MediaRecorder setMaxDuration fails

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mediarecorder, android-8.1-oreo

My Videorecording app worked well so far, I'm since calling `_mediaRecorder.SetMaxDuration(120000)` which calls back a MediaRecordInfo where `event.What == MediaRecorderInfo.MaxDurationReached` after two minutes.

Suprisingly on Android 8.1 this callback comes immediately after starting the mediarecorder.

If I don't set a max duration I can capture videos longer than a sec on 8.1 as well.

7.0 and 9.0 don't have this issue.

Any ideas?

Here's some code, although I have no Idea were the issue arises, I could just paste my whole video classes.

```
    private void SetupMediaRecorder()
    {
        MediaRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
        MediaRecorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Surface);
        MediaRecorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mpeg4);

        MediaRecorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264);
        MediaRecorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Aac);
        MediaRecorder.SetOutputFile(outputURL);
        MediaRecorder.SetVideoSize(1280, 720);
        //Modify for changes in output size & quality
        MediaRecorder.SetVideoFrameRate(30);
        MediaRecorder.SetVideoEncodingBitRate(2000000);
        //MediaRecorder.SetVideoSize(videoSize.Width, videoSize.Height);
        MediaRecorder.SetMaxDuration(120000);

        //Set audio bitrate
        int bitDepth = 16;
        int sampleRate = 44100;
        int bitRate = sampleRate * bitDepth;
        MediaRecorder.SetAudioEncodingBitRate(bitRate);
        MediaRecorder.SetAudioSamplingRate(sampleRate);

        int rotation = (int)ThisActivity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;
        int orientation = orientations[rotation];
        MediaRecorder.SetOrientationHint(orientation);
        MediaRecorder.Prepare();
    }


    private void MediaRecorder_Info(object sender, MediaRecorder.InfoEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.What == MediaRecorderInfo.MaxDurationReached)
        {
            //Called immediately after MediaRecorder.Start() on Android 8.1
        }
    }
```

Comment: By any chance can you share some relevant code? Maybe there could be something specific causing this and not OS?

Comment: I posted some code, but mentioned, that it worked flawless on 7.0 and 9.0 so far, it was used by many users and devices so far. Galaxy Tab A 6 with Android 8.1 just doesn't worked (tested 2 of these devices, same specs)

Comment: So the issue is with Galaxy Tab A 6? Have you tested Android 8.1 with any other device?

Comment: Mhh you might have a point. I just checked the 3 devices that were tested now, all of them are Galaxy Tab A 6, 8.1. I'm certain that it worked on this tablet before, most likely before 8.1.